# How to add or modify systemd mount targets/conditions in unit file

Tags: systemd, networkmanager, automounting, cifs, systemd-unit

I've got a .mount file that I globbed together as /etc/systemd/system/opt-hass-config.mount

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount the config dir of hass.mydomain.com
[Mount]
What=//[IP ADDRESS]/config
Where=/opt/hass/config
Type=cifs
Options=username=[PASSWORD],password=[USERNAME],domain=[DOMAIN],uid=1000,gid=1000,forceuid,forcegid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It works just fine, however I use a laptop, and it's going to fail when I'm not at work, and wireguard hasn't been brought up yet, wireguard is through networkmanager, poking around I've found  with `systemctl list-dependencies opt-hass-addons.mount` That's it is going to wait for network manager to do it's thing, is there any way to set it to wait until wireguard is connected, or perhaps it can connect to the network where opt-hass-addons lives?

I see there are things like [this ping the gateway systemd thing](https://gist.github.com/raspi/54bd758a6e981d3379ad83c9458b0bcc) but how do I tell a .mount not to go until something else happens?  I've put cifs into /etc/fstab before, and when there's a connection issue, things wouldn't boot until I removed/commented them out, or was able to connect to them, I don't want that.

Comment: I would suggest you look at this the other way around - make the opt-haass-addons.mount as a dependency to your wireguard (or whatever it is) service that needs to start. Make the wireguard service execute the mount after it's been started.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense, thank you